# Vector space: $\forall a\in K, v \in E ( a \cdot_E v=0_E \to a=0_K \lor v=0_E)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove the following:

let $E$ vector space on $K$, then $\forall a\in K, v \in E ( a \cdot_E v=0_E \to a=0_K \lor  v=0_E)$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove that if $a v = 0_E$ (I take there's a misprint in you formula, and I'm simplifying notation a bit), and $a \ne 0_K$, then $v = 0_E$.

Now if $a \ne 0_K$, then $a$ has an inverse $a^{-1}$ in the field $K$.

Thus
$$
0_E = a^{-1} \cdot 0_E = a^{-1} (a v) = (a^{-1} a) v = 1 v = v.
$$

Comment: true... of course!!! I did not remember the axioms of vector space... thank you soo much!!!

Comment: @GarnakOlegovitc, you're welcome!